# How to transfer very long string array from C# to Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: c#, json, twitter-bootstrap, exchange-server, visual-studio-2017

I'm currently working on a new "dashboard like" website where I need to show all message from an exchange 2016 mailbox (like gmail or any bootstrap email client template).

Currently, I'm able to retrieve the messages from the mailbox without problem by using the EWS API.

My problem is I really don't know which format (XML or JSON) is better to return the message content (ID,Body,subject and DateTimeReceived). I tried to store all messages in a multidimenssional array and a jagged array but when I tried to serialize them in a JSON string, I always get an "Unexpected token" error.

So my two questions are:

1) Is it better to use XML format than JSON considering the message's body can be a very long string?

2) Is there a better way to achieve what I what to do rather than an array converted by a JQuery script?

PS: I'm working on Visual Studio 2017 and the language used is C# with a bootstrap dashboard template. Also, I am totally new to web development(language, good coding habits and etc) but not to C# programming.

Here's my function to extract all messages from the mailbox and return a multidimensional array :

```
public string[,] getEmail() {
 ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);

 service.AutodiscoverUrl("testUser@myworkplace.com");
 service.TraceEnabled = true;
 service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
 service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
 PropertySet itempropertyset = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
 itempropertyset.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;
 ItemView itemview = new ItemView(1000);
 itemview.PropertySet = itempropertyset;
 FindItemsResults < Item > findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, itemview);

 string[, ] emailArray = new string[findResults.TotalCount, 4];
 int i = 0;

 foreach(Item item in findResults.Items) {
  message.Load(itempropertyset);

  emailArray[i, 0] = message.Id.ToString();
  emailArray[i, 1] = message.Subject;
  emailArray[i, 2] = message.Body;
  emailArray[i, 3] = message.DateTimeReceived.ToString();

  i++;
 }

 return emailArray;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `when I tried to serialize them in a JSON string, I always get an "Unexpected token" error.`  Sounds like you have a bum character that needs escaping.  Are you getting this error when you try to read the string in the Javascript?  Or turning the object INTO a string in C#?

Comment: My problem was related to how I called the serialize method. Now I simply call my method with this and it's working as expected with this code:

       `public string getBody() {
            var javaScriptSerializer = new
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            string jsonString = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(emailBody);
            return jsonString;
       ` }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to get the data up to a web browser, you're most likely better off going with JSON.  The browser has native code to parse JSON strings, and it's a very easy format both to create and parse.

That being said, you should still find a library to do the encoding for you.  Pretty much all platforms will have some code to convert a set of nested Maps and Arrays to a JSON string, and that will help you avoid minor (but fatal) errors in actually formatting & parsing the document.

See also: [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)